# Lato Font using @font-family not appearing

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to use the font Lato Regular in my html/css. The problem is, whenever I load the html file, it shows the regular font (in blahblahblah). I inspected that element, and it detects that the font-family should be 'LatoWeb'. However, LatoWeb shows the regular system font. I am running this in Linux Firefox btw

This is my HTML code (html code is saved under app/views/static_pages)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>UPrint</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/stylesheets/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/stylesheets/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/stylesheets/landing.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/stylesheets/latostyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="landing-page-description">
        <img class="ui centered medium image" src="../../assets/images/logo.png">
        <p class="regular"> blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

This is my css code filename landing.css (css codes saved under app/assets/stylesheets)
(Fonts are saved in app/assets/fonts)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoWeb';
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}


body {
  background-color: #3fabad;
}

.landing-page-description {
  position: relative;
}

.regular {
  font-family: 'LatoWeb';
}
```

Comment: Well you aren't closing your `p` tag for a start

Comment: edited my code. still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a Google font for Lato. It seems that using a font from your computer is a problem with Mozilla Firefox :( have to edit about:config

Answer (score 0):

Please try `!important`. I'm not sure it's working or not. but u should try. because the default fonts overwrite our own fonts.

Comment: where should I put !important?

Comment: font-family: 'LatoWeb' !important;

Comment: in both. where you attached your @font-face, and where you apply font on regular class.

Answer (score -1):

This should be comment but not enough reputation

Check in your browser console (Firebug) if your paths are resolved correctly.

Comment: the file landing.css is saved in assets/stylesheets. It is not in assets/stylesheets/fonts

Comment: @Danooned What won't work? Checking in Firebug or console? That's what its for, troubleshooting.